# python pandas if column string contains word flag

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy

I want to add a flag to my python pandas dataframe df, if an entry in the column `Title`contains the word `test` (upper or lower case or all Uppercase), I would like to add `T` in a new column `test`.

This gives me an error and does not account for all uppercase scenarios:

```
df['Test_Flag'] = np.where(df[df['Title'].str.contains("test|Test")==True], 'T', '')

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with parameter `case=False`and `na=False`:

```
df['Test_Flag'] = np.where(df['Title'].str.contains("test", case=False, na=False), 'T', '')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title':['test','Test',np.nan, 'a']})
df['Test_Flag'] = np.where(df['Title'].str.contains("test", case=False, na=False), 'T', '')
print (df)
  Title Test_Flag
0  test         T
1  Test         T
2   NaN          
3     a
```

Comment: how can I account for all uppercase scenarios like 'TEST'?

Comment: I think need parameter `case=False`

Comment: Thank you - I tried it, but it also applied the flag to blank rows

Comment: Then need another parameter - `na=False`, check edited answer.