# Python pandas: how to assign value to new column if key is in other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe and want to check if any part of the string from one column is a key from a given dictionary and if so, assign the value of this key to a new column.

```
dict = {'Apple': 'Fruit', 'Chicken': 'Meat'}

expected df:

#     String           New Column
# 1   'Red apple'      'Fruit'
# 2   'Fried chicken'  'Meat'
```

I found this post which is very close to what I need to do but I couldn't find a solution with for using a dictionary: [python pandas if column string contains word flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055050/python-pandas-if-column-string-contains-word-flag)

I hope this makes sense, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to change all key's character to upper case in your `dict` and your df , then we just `apply` with checking function

```
d={x.upper(): y for x,y in d.items()}

df['New']=df.String.str.upper().apply(lambda x : ''.join([v if k in x  else '' for k,v in d.items()]))

df
          String    New
0      Red apple  Fruit
1  Fried chicken   Meat
```

Comment: A great solution +1. Any specific reason to go for uppercase?

Comment: @HarvIpan The key of dict is Apple but in df it is apple :-)

Comment: @Wen: Awesome! Thank you so much! :-)